# Accurev workspace creation issue

Tags: workspace, accurev

I have deleted the workspace from accurev. Now when I am again creating the workspace. It's giving error that workspace already exists. How can I resolve this?

update: Is there any accurev plugin through which i can directly promote the code to accurev strean using IBM RSA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workspaces and streams are never really removed due to the time-safe architecture; they are deactivated and can later be reactivated. This also means that a workspace or stream owns every name it's ever had. You will need to create the new workspace with a new, unique name.

Comment: In the GUI, click on "include hidden streams" -> find your workspace -> right click -> reactivate.

Answer (score 1):

Via the command line, "**accurev reactivate wspace** *workspaceName*"